# How to send an email with any video file

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am using asp.net c# and i want to send an email with a video file. When i send an video in iframe format via email, email has been sending proper but video is not showing on email. I also check with send on gmail ,yahoo etc but I didn't got.

So it is possible or not. If yes that how can i set video in my email body.

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/05/html5-and-video-in-email/ https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/video-in-email/ may be of interest.

Comment: @ mjwills. Have you any reference source of this type of example

Comment: @NaveenSoni go to the section named "The final code" in his first link

Comment: @NaveenSoni You could use https://campaignmonitor.com (or another similar option - Campaign Monitor is my employer) to build an email with a video and see how it does it. I assume MailChimp and other competitors have something similar too.

Comment: @mjwills  Okay, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related to asp.net, nor c#. Your problem is related to using iframes inside html encoded emails. I would find surprising if email clients would not filter iframes (they are not considered secure)

Your best choice would be adding an image with a link to the video URL. Other alternatives could be attaching the video to the email, or trying HTML5 video tag (and cross fingers that the email client understands it)

Comment: So Iframe will never used in email, Right?

Comment: You could but almost all email clients would block the iframe it or detect the email as spam. I would advice HTML5 video tag or just add a link to your website.

Comment: Okay! thaks for your response